# Problema al copiar en portapapeles Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

!Buenas!

*Antes de nada, quiero aclarar que ya he leído varias preguntas/respuestas del foro y ninguna aclara mi problema.*

Estoy terminando un pequeño proyecto, el cual es una APP que genera contraseñas aleatoriamente. El problema está cuando deseo copiar la contraseña almacenada en un `textView` en el portapapeles.

Con este código me guarda el texto cuando lo **mantengo pulsado**:

```
public void copiar(View view) {

    if(etiqueta.getText().equals("")) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "No hay contraseña para copiar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        etiqueta.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // obtenemos el texto de entrada
                String text = etiqueta.getText().toString();
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("",  text);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                return true;
            }
        });


        Toast.makeText(this, "Contraseña copiada al portapapeles", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Pero no lanza este:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Contraseña copiada al portapapeles", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

La idea es que cuando el usuario **pulse** y no **mantenga pulsado** el texto, se copie a el portapapeles y muestre el:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Contraseña copiada al portapapeles", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Y cuando entre en el condicional que iguala a una cadena vacia, salte este otro (sin copiar nada):

```
Toast.makeText(this, "No hay contraseña para copiar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Dejo también la parte de **XML**:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/milabel"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="copiar"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.238" />
```

Así que, ¿Como puedo hacer que el usuario **pulse** y copie la contraseña al portapapeles? Y muestre el `Toast.makeText`.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: me da que vas a tener que meter el Toast dentro de la función onLongClick, justo antes del return

Comment: Lo intenté @Juanant pero me sale el siguiente error: `Cannot resolve method 'makeText(anonymous android.view.View.OnLongClickListener, java.lang.String, int)'`

Comment: debe de funcionar (antes del return), solo cambia this por getApplicationContext() ó por tuActivity.this para que no de error el toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví.

Gracias al comentario de **@armen**, intenté esto:

```
etiqueta.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                if(!etiqueta.getText().equals("")) {
                    String text = etiqueta.getText().toString();
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", text);
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contraseña copiada al portapapeles", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Con solo un par de modificaciones para ajustar el código a mi necesidad, y ya funciona a la perfección. Dejo la respuesta por si alguien necesita ayuda con esto mismo.